# Array performance and how to get performance of independent variables

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am writing a Java project which uses a custom object - smallObject, which is mainly composed of double variables.

Now as the project evolved, I required that every variable in smallObject becomes an array of 4 elements - so what was a double variable, became an array of type double, with 4 elements - bigObject.

The processes that use bigObject are exactly the same as smallObject, with the only difference being that they contain an element number, so smallObject.a = 4, becomes bigObject.a[2] = 4;

I was expecting that since every time I am accessing the array, I define exactly which element I require (don't have to search for it), the performance should be approximately the same, however, performance slowed down by a factor of 2-3. These objects are used in arraylists and queues which can grow up to 3 million elements.

Is it to be expected that performance slows down? How can I go around this issue? Was thinking of using individual variables (a[4], becomes a1, a2, a3, a4) - but this would require me to have different classes so that each one accesses the right variable and will make the code unreadable.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Array access always involves bounds checking, adding a performance hit that may become significant.

Comment: Code snippet could help for answer.

Comment: You may suffer from bounds checking and (probably more) bad data locality. The hack of replacing arrays by individual variables would probably help, but there are simpler ways. We'd need some code first...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, if u use list-based objects to find an element in position 4 you have to go from 1 to 4 since lists are based on pointers (O(n) where n is the number of elements of the array if u are used to big O notation). If u use simpler elements like a true double array accessing element 4 should be done in 1 operation O(1)... so try to use double[].
Hope that this helps you.
Alex

Comment: Only `LinkedList` has `O(n)` access, and the OP was already using arrays. Answer is wrong and misses the point of the question completely.